# Using REST services directly from the browser via Javascript

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, architecture

What are the pros and cons of consuming web services within an HTML page via Javascript (JQuery)?

```
Browser (JS) -> Backend (REST)
```

versus

```
Browser (JS) -> MVC backend -> Web services backend (REST)
```

What is the best practice about handling authentication in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers only allow a page to issue AJAX queries to the domain from which the page originated. This prevents cross-site scripting, a nasty attack method.

If you control the domain, AJAX is very useful.

If you don't control the domain, you should setup a server which requests the data and serves it (either on page load, or through AJAX) to the desired subpage.

Comment: This is true if the backend server doesn't support CORS.  If it does, then a browser can make requests to a server hosted someplace other than the server that hosted the web application.  Not that making CORS work all the time is especially easy...

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest not making a browser to backend call if there is authentication in the picture. Even if your backend supports CORS, you would have to tack on API security on top of it (something like OAUth)for user authentication and manage all of that (error handling, spoofing, etc) on the client. It would be easier if you just make that call from a middle tier application.